# How to create Postgres table with Identity as GENERATED ALWAYS using Fluent Migrator?

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-migrator

My Fluent migrator code :

```cs
Create.Table("Players")
    .WithColumn("Id"       ).AsInt32().NotNullable().PrimaryKey().Identity()
    .WithColumn("FirstName").AsString();
```

Generated SQL is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.Players (
    id     serial4      NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Players PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But I want the id as `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` instead of `serial4`.

Expected table creation SQL is :

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.Players (
    id     int4         NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "PK_Players" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I don't know how to achieve this using fluent migrator.

Could you please provide solutions or suggestions?

---

Configurations

````
private static IServiceProvider CreateServices( IConfiguration configuration )
{
    return new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IConventionSet>( new DefaultConventionSet( configuration.GetSection("TenantName").Value, null )
        )
        .AddFluentMigratorCore()
            .ConfigureRunner( r => r
                .AddPostgres()
                .WithGlobalConnectionString(  configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection" ) )
                                                    
                .WithRunnerConventions( new MigrationRunnerConventions() )
                .ScanIn( typeof( Migrations.CoreInitialMigration ).Assembly ).For.Migrations()
            )
            .BuildServiceProvider(false);
}

private static void UpdateDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // Instantiate the runner
    var runner = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMigrationRunner>();
    
    // Execute the migrations
    runner.MigrateUp();
}

In StartUp.cs

```csharp
var serviceProvider = CreateServices(Configuration);
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    UpdateDatabase(scope.ServiceProvider);
}
````

Comment: What versions of PostgreSQL and FluentMigrator are you using?

Comment: FluentMigrator version is 3.3.0 and PostgreSQL version is 12.12

Comment: Please post your `ConfigureServices` method and confirm **exactly** which `static class` you're getting those column-builder extension methods from (e.g. `PrimaryKey()`, `Identity()`).

Comment: Curiously, I can't find any mention of `serial4` inside FluentMigrator's source-code... I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: Sorry I don't know , I guess may be handled by postgre based on size of the integer

Comment: ConfigureServices added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FluentMigrator does seems to support `GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY`](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/blob/master/src/FluentMigrator.Runner.Postgres/Generators/Postgres/Postgres10_0Column.cs) - so the problem is caused by your (lack of) configuration.

Your `ConfigureServices` method currently has this:

```cs
.AddFluentMigratorCore()
.ConfigureRunner( r => r
    .AddPostgres()
    .WithGlobalConnectionString( configuration.GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) )
    .WithRunnerConventions( new MigrationRunnerConventions() )
    .ScanIn( typeof(Migrations.CoreInitialMigration).Assembly ).For.Migrations()
)
```

Your use of `.AddPostgres()` will configure FluentMigrator to assume you're using an old version of Postgres - I'm unsure which version exactly but it looks like *some version* older than Postgres 9.2.

...but `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` [was introduced in Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtable.html) ([observe how `AS IDENTITY` isn't in the 9.x docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createtable.html)), so you need to change `AddPostgres()` to `AddPostgres10_0()` or higher, such as `AddPostgres11_0()`.

[You can see these extension methods here](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/blob/e40e221007a3a12b4e487284f1201f61bec3af4e/src/FluentMigrator.Runner.Postgres/PostgresRunnerBuilderExtensions.cs).

So change your code to this:

```cs
.AddFluentMigratorCore()
.ConfigureRunner( r => r
    .AddPostgres11_0()
    .WithGlobalConnectionString( configuration.GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) )
    .WithRunnerConventions( new MigrationRunnerConventions() )
    .ScanIn( typeof(Migrations.CoreInitialMigration).Assembly ).For.Migrations()
)
```

...and it should just-work.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Now sql for the Id column is `id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`